# Java Regex OR operator not working properly

Tags: java, regex

I have this Strings :

```
String test1=":test:block1:%a1%a2%a3%a4:block2:BL";
```

and

```
String test2=":test:block2:BL:block1:%a1%a2%a3%a4";
```

I've created an regex pattern in order to isolate this piece of String

```
 block1:%a1%a2%a3%a4:
```

from the rest of the String letting those Strings like this :

```
in the case of test1="block1:%a1%a2%a3%a4:"; (with ':' at the end)
in the case of test2=":block1:%a1%a2%a3%a4"; (with ':' at the beggining)
```

The regex i've created is :

```
"(block1:(.*?):|:block1:(.*))";
```

With test1 is working , but with test2 is retrieving me this :

```
block1:%a1%a2%a3%a4:block2:BL";
```

Can someone give me a hand with this ?

Cheers!

Comment: *"but with test2 is retrieving me this : `block1:%a1%a2%a3%a4:block2:BL";`"* What are you quoting there? I'm quite certain you're not getting back the text in a different order than in the string, so I'm guessing part of that is the content of a capture group or something?

Comment: "(block1:(.*?):|block1:(.*))"; - Delete : infront of second block1

Comment: I suspect you just want `block1:([^:]*)`, see https://regex101.com/r/BLVvOM/2

Comment: I tried both answers and the test2 is still returning block1:%a1%a2%a3%a4:block2:BL without the ':' at the begining

Comment: Can you post a real code excerpt? It seems that nobody really understands what you are trying to achieve...

Comment: [Try this](https://regex101.com/r/exEGjh/2): `(block1:(.*?):|:block1:([^:]*)$)`

Comment: It worked ! – rv7 .

Comment: Thanks to everyone!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may use

```
block1:([^:]*)
```

It matches `block1:` text and then captures into Group 1 any 0 or more chars other than `:`.

See [Java demo](https://ideone.com/0C01Ut):

```
String patternString = "block1:([^:]*)";
String[] tests = {":test:block1:%a1%a2%a3%a4:block2:BL",
                  ":test:block2:BL:block1:%a1%a2%a3%a4"};
for (int i=0; i<tests.length; i++)
{
    Pattern p = Pattern.compile(patternString, Pattern.DOTALL);
    Matcher m = p.matcher(tests[i]);
    if(m.find())
    {
        System.out.println(tests[i] + " matched. Match: " +
                    m.group(0) + ", Group 1: " + m.group(1));
    }
}
```

Output:

```
:test:block1:%a1%a2%a3%a4:block2:BL matched. Match: block1:%a1%a2%a3%a4, Group 1: %a1%a2%a3%a4
:test:block2:BL:block1:%a1%a2%a3%a4 matched. Match: block1:%a1%a2%a3%a4, Group 1: %a1%a2%a3%a4
```